# How can I send the email currently being composed via code with GMail Addons

Tags: email, google-apps-script, gmail, gmail-addons

I am trying to create essentially a new send button for my GMail add-on but I am unsure if it is possible.

The send function requires an object to send but I can not find a way to grab the email being currently composed so i have tried sending the draft that corresponds to the email being composed.

```
var draft = GmailApp.getDrafts()[0]; // The first draft message in the drafts folder 
var msg = draft.send(); // Send it
```

This half works as it sends the email in the background but the compose window stays open so its hard to tell its sent and further more there are cases where the composed email either does not get saved as a draft or it is not at the top of the saved drafts.

Is there anyway to send the email currently being composed?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not feasible, the [Gmail Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail) will only allow you to take the draft's messages, therefore you can't take the composed message.

The problem about not getting the message when it's not saved it's because Gmail waits a moment before saving automatically the composed message as a draft.

If you want, you can submit a Feature Request on [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/), so Google can take into consideration adding the functionality you are requiring.